# Use a compiled WPF control (a dll) in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I've downloaded [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/700185/Windows-Progress-Ring?msg=4884207#xx4884207xx) user-control which is developed in WPF, but I would like to know if exists the chance to use the dll in WF (the dll where is the user-control), of course sadly if I try to add the control in the ToolBox doesn't appears for WF projects, only for WPF.

I've found this article in MSDN that describes that WinForms controls can loaded in WPF projects

· [Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So, it can be done the reversed thing to use an WPF control in a WF project?

Comment: errr... thanks but this question does not have an answer. I didn't knew the info that yu've provided but they are only explaining how to use "ElementHost" to add a control, yes, but creating it in XAML, a WPF project control (uncompiled), I'm asking about how to add the compiled dll to use the user-contorl that is inside that dll, in case that could be possible.

Comment: @user2864740 yes you are right, sorry my english is not very good sometimes I do not emphasize in the proper way, I've solved it by referencing the dll, but there is no way to use it in design-time?, feel free to write an answer 'cause your suggestion solved my problem, but if you could help me to know whether I could manage the control at design-time in the UI i will appreciate it, I've seen that this can be done with "ElementHost" does not detect my referenced dll to do that, thanks

Comment: Also I noticed that the WPF control is not recognized a a "Control" type so I can't add it manualy in the code...

Comment: WPF controls inherit from `System.Windows.Controls.Control` while WinForms inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` - so while they are both Controls, they are derived from *different* "Control" classes. Thus in a mixed project it may be confusing to simply use `Control` and I would recommend using `Forms.Control` and/or `Controls.Control` to disambiguate the types.

Comment: The method `Form.Controls.Add()` does not accept a `System.Windows.Controls.Control`, this should not be a problem but yes its a problem 'cause even selecting/checking the WPF control in the menu of the toolbox (in the WPF Components tab) it does not appear in my WinForms toolbox so I don't know how to procceed

Comment: See http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms - after referencing the project and adding an ElementHost, set the "[Select] Hosted Content" property of the ElementHost itself.

Comment: In Resume: I've referenced the WPF dll and the WF project compiled well, in the ToolBox menu the WPF control was selected by default but it does not appear in my WF toolbox, so I can't find the way to add this control in the UI 'case also the `Form.Controls.Add()` fails to add the control throwing a wrong type exception. I've tried to convert the type and rebuild the project, no way.

Comment: @user2864740 yes I understood that point but I'm not referencing the project I've referenced the compiled dll, it is full necessary to also reference the project? 'cause in other WPF controls I don't have the source code.

Comment: You can reference the Project *or* the DLL, but it must be referenced.

Comment: I've referenced the WPF dll and after that I've compiled the WF project to apply changes in the elementHost, but as I'm trying to explain the WPF control does not appear inside the dropdownlist of the elementhost. If I upload the project you could revise it for faults or something?, thanks for your help

Comment: Here is the WinForms project if someone could verify what is wrong, it has the WPF dll referenced (inside the Bin folder): http://www.mediafire.com/download/ied1g784u8532n8/WindowsApplication8.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `.Child` property to your WPF control.

[image]